# How can I construct this 301 Permanently Moved rule with NGINX?

Tags: nginx

My dynamically generated pages' URLs used to be like this:

```
http://domain.tld/folder/dynamic_label_1/dynamic_label_2/the_rest_...
```

All pages however now, are moved to:

```
http://domain.tld/folder/dynamic_label_2-dynamic_label_1/the_rest_...
```

Note: the last part of these pages are optional > the_rest_.. Meaning, there isn't always something after **dynamic_label_2-dynamic_label_1/**

I'm fairly new to Nginx and can not figure out how to set this redirect rule.

My question is:

What is the redirect rule for nginx server here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, this should do it -

```
rewrite  ^/folder/(\w+)/(\w+)(.*)$  /folder/$2-$1$3  break;
```

I'm assuming `\w` would be enough for your `dynamic_label`. If not, feel free to add the characters inside the `(\w+)` parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

The following *rewrite* to be inserted into your virtual host, in *location* (or *server*)

```
rewrite ^/folder/dynamic_label_1/dynamic_label_2(.*)$  /folder/dynamic_label_2-dynamic_label_1$1  break;
```

Edit based on comment

```
rewrite ^/folder/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/.*)?$  /folder/$2-$1$3  break;
```

The *optional* part (including the optional leading `/`) is in `$3`.

Comment: Hello @ring0! Thank you for the answer but here, dunamic_label_ should be *dynamic* as in, they can be any string. x, y, z .. *folder* is always the same, two strings afterwards should be changed from a/b to b-a. Could you help me with that please? Would it be ^/folder/$1/$2/$3 /folder/$2-$1/$3 ? How can I make $3 optional though? Thank you.

Comment: Edited the answer to fit the requirement.